# Upgrade to a faster server but MySQL server is getting slower

Tags: mysql, cpu, benchmarking, ram

Due to our business expansion, we decided to upgrade our web application + database server,
we had :

```
CPU : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz (8 cores)
RAM : 32 GB
HDD : 2*3 TB in RAID 1
```

the new one:

```
CPU : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz * 2  ( 24 cores) 
RAM : 128 GB
HDD : 1 SSD 300 GB
```

but what I noticed that MySQL is running considerably slower ,
example: for one of my slowest queries ( 3 level nested )

```
old one: 8 seconds ; new one: 14 seconds
```

I did sysbench to check this and the result were contradictory : http://speedy.sh/GJ3hM/bench-sql.txt

both of them have the default configuration of mysql.

Comment: Your cores are slower. Everything that happens on a single core will be slower if CPU-bound. In essence: individual cpu-bound queries will be slower, but you can run more in parallel, which would normally be more typical of database usage (high concurrency), but your current use may differ.

Comment: BTW: you're very sure you want a non-raid SSD (which are still(?) known to fail sooner)?

Comment: If you run default configuration of MySQL.. why did you upgrade your servers? By default MySQL uses 8 megabytes of RAM (InnoDB) to store hot data set.. you have 32 gb in your old system and 128 in your new one. Please optimize your MySQL settings before doing like.. ANYTHING else.

Comment: I set the default config just to do a benchmark apple-to-apple.

Comment: any good suggestion to optimize my MySQL config?

Comment: Use InnoDB and increase `innodb_buffer_pool` value to a huge value. On a setup with 128GB of ram, I would (personally) set it to 100 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the the software environment remains unchanged (i.e., MySQL settings, 
configurations, Operating system, client version etc), it totally makes sense that your newer server is slower, because the CPU clock frequency is slower (3.4 GHz vs 2.1 GHz).

If you go to the general CPU benchmark website such as http://www.cpubenchmark.net/, they assign a score to each CPU. That score is based on many factors such as the number of core/thread, clock speed, cache, memory speed etc. Each factor may have a different weight, e.g., number of core is more important than the clock speed. It is a general score, it does not apply to all applications and all situations.

We had an exact the same situation like yours. We upgraded our LAMP stack from Xeon E3-1240 3.4 GHz 8 thread (score: 9264) to Xeon E5-2440 1.9GHz 16 thread (score: 9425). I expect the performance will be similar. Turns out the average loading time of our web application (PHP + MySQL) increased from 0.8 seconds to 2.6 seconds, given the software environment remains unchanged. We learned that the CPU clock speed is the main factor to the overall performance.

So I think the CPU score is totally misleading and it does not apply to every situation. In the future, if you want to know the performance of your application with the new CPU, you may want to rent a server on the cloud with a similar specs. That will give you an idea how well your application will perform on the new hardware.

Comment: Throughput / ability to handle many requests in parallel should be higher with more cores, but single-threaded performance (~= latency when a single request can't take advantage of multiple cores) scales with clock speed (and microarchitecture version).  The OP changed from Xeon ... v2 (IvyBridge) to a different Xeon ... v2 (also IvyBridge), but you didn't even list the v1 / v2 / v3 / v4 number.  [v4 is Broadwell](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/31/intel_broadwell_ep_xeon_e5_2600_v4/), for example. Depending on the workload, AVX2 support might allow a big speedup (but not for DB I think).

Comment: Anyway, yes, measuring multi-core CPUs on a single axis with a one-dimensional number is nonsense.  If your workload is similar to the benchmark that spat out that number, it's useful.  Otherwise it isn't.  Same goes for a lot of benchmarks or metrics.

Comment: According to the original question, the author noticed that the SQL query has slowed down after the upgrade. Running a single SQL query use only single thread. That's why I tried to answer based on the CPU clock speed.

Comment: My point was just that more cores does have a benefit, but single-threaded performance isn't one of them.  Also that a newer-generation CPU will usually be a bit faster at the same clock speed, and potentially a lot faster for workloads that get a big speedup from AVX2. And also to agree with you that measuring CPU performance with a single number is bogus.